# Convert SAS self inner join to PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sas, inner-join, self-join

I have been trying to convert the below SAS code into PySpark syntax, but I haven't been able to figure out the dates.

```sql
inner join (select var1, max(date) as max_date
from table
group by var1) as recent
on a.var1 = recent.var1 and a.date = recent.date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For self joins in Spark, it's recommended to use `alias` for both sides.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = (table.alias('a')
    .join(
        table.groupBy('var1').agg(F.max('date').alias('date')).alias('recent'),
        (F.col("a.var1") == F.col("recent.var1")) & (F.col("a.date") == F.col("recent.date")),
        'inner')
)
```

If you don't need duplicated columns, remove them by selecting everything from the first dataframe.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = (table.alias('a')
    .join(
        table.groupBy('var1').agg(F.max('date').alias('date')).alias('recent'),
        (F.col("a.var1") == F.col("recent.var1")) & (F.col("a.date") == F.col("recent.date")),
        'inner')
    .select('a.*')
)
```